# SED expression for turning Yeseva+One into --font-yeseva-one: "Yeseva One";

Tags: css, bash, sed, grep, google-font-api

I have a series of font values like this (Command separated one line):

```
Yeseva+One, Yrsa, ...
```

I'm looking for a SED (Or other bash tool expression) for turn each value into line statements like this:

```
--font-yeseva-one: "Yeseva One";
--font-yrsa: "Yrsa";
```

Thoughts?

### Update

Just wanted to say thanks for all the great help with this and if anyone needs google fonts as CSS variables / properties they are all available here (MIT License):
https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-variables-fonts/blob/master/src/main/css/index.css

I'll also be providing utilities for using google fonts here:
https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-utilities-fonts

Comment: What other values could be present as a de-limiter other than `+` in `Yeseva+One`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

variable="Abc, Def+Hola, Ghij"

IFS="[, ]"
for i in $variable
do
        a=`echo "$i" | sed 's/\+/ /g'`
        i=`echo "$i" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed 's/\+/\-/g'`
        echo "--font-$i: \"$a\";"
done
```

Please check, I have checked it on my machine and it works fine!

Output:

```
--font-abc: "Abc";
--font-def-hola: "Def Hola";
--font-ghij: "Ghij";
```

Comment: Thanks - Almost there ... I love the simplicity of it BTW - very easy to follow - however some of the output looks like this: --font--abhaya+libre:  Abhaya+Libre
... and it needs to look like this --font--abhaya-libre:  "Abhaya Libre"

Comment: Hey @Ole, I think the same code works for me when I add "Abhaya+Libre" to the list of input parameters. Please tell me if I am missing something.

Comment: Works perfectly now - Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** approach:

```
s="Yeseva+One, Yrsa, Courier+New, Alegreya+Sans+SC"
awk -F", " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){k=gensub("+","-","g",$i);
     v=gensub("+"," ","g",$i);printf "--font-%s: \"%s\";\n",tolower(k),v;}}' <<< $s
```

The output:

```
--font-yeseva-one: "Yeseva One";
--font-yrsa: "Yrsa";
--font-courier-new: "Courier New";
--font-alegreya-sans-sc: "Alegreya Sans SC";
```

`-F", "` - field separator

`(i=1;i<=NF;i++)` - iterating through all the fields

`k=gensub("+","-","g",$i);` - replacing all `+` with `-` (for font key attribute)

`v=gensub("+"," ","g",$i);` - replacing all `+` with  (for font value)

Comment: Hi - I put the above in a script and I got the following: ./script2.sh: 7: ./script2.sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
... is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Ole, test it on command line. Another way to pass the input is `echo "Yeseva+One, Yrsa, Courier+New" | awk -F", " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){k=gensub("+","-",1,$i);
     v=gensub("+"," ",1,$i);printf "--font-%s: \"%s\";\n",tolower(k),v;}}'`

Answer (score 0):

With Pure Bash :

```
IFS="[, ]" read -r -a list <<<"Yeseva+One, Yrsa"  #Convert values to array
for k in "${list[@]}";do 
  k2="${k,,}" #The bash way to convert everything from upper to lower
  printf -- '--font-%s:\"%s\";\n' "${k2//+/-}" "${k//+/ }"  #bash way to replace strings
done
#Output
--font-yeseva-one:"Yeseva One";
--font-yrsa:"Yrsa";
```

Comment: Thanks George - This is really helping me get up to speed on scripting!